# If you delete a question with a positive score will your reputation go down? If so, how long does it take?

Tags: support, questions, down-votes, up-votes, deleted-posts

If you delete a question with a positive score will you get reputation back? Basically what I'm asking is, suppose you have a question with a score of 22, and I delete the question. Would I lose reputation? If so, how long does it take  for it to re-calculate the reputation?

Comment: Yes, you'll gain the reputation back.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how long does it take for it to re-calculate the reputation?

Comment: i saw one post that said 6 months! @Glorfindel

Comment: *Deletions will have a much more immediate effect on reputation, not waiting on a recalc (but reputation sync takes up to 5 minutes on a delete/undelete action; as to not block the user's response thread, it's offloaded to a background queue)*

Comment: any response to  the edits i made? @Glorfindel

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount  Deleting your questions might get you in worse trouble than loosing reputation. And sure, you'll also loose reputation if you delete upvoted questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how so?

Comment: @Glorfindel to back my 6 months comment:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36050/if-i-delete-my-question-with-some-up-votes-what-will-be-the-effect-on-my-reputa

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount You may read up here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount And with deleted questions, it's even harder to get out.

Comment: @Glorfindel "I've only had one rep recalc in about 6 months, so results may vary. You might not see a rep hit for quite some time. But take into account, you will lose all rep received from deleted upvotes eventually."

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount _""I've only had one rep recalc in about 6 months, so results may vary."_ There's no such thing. You are probably talking bout something completely different.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36050/if-i-delete-my-question-with-some-up-votes-what-will-be-the-effect-on-my-reputa
?????

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount I don't know which kind of recalc the OP there talks about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the recalculation that was commonplace *eight years ago*.

Comment: i see. @Glorfindel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [post you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36050) in 
 the comments is **eight years old** and describes a situation that is no longer the case.

When a post is deleted which affected your reputation (whether that is because it's your post and it received up- or downvotes, you suggested an edit on it and got +2 reputation from the approval, it's an answer and you downvoted it, costing 1 reputation, etc., etc.) your reputation will be recalculated in [5 minutes, give or take](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes):

> Deletions will have a much more immediate effect on reputation, not waiting on a recalc (but reputation sync takes up to 5 minutes on a delete/undelete action; as to not block the user's response thread, it's offloaded to a background queue)

The only exception is when a post you wrote has [a score of 3 or more and is at least 60 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232). Reputation gained/lost from that post will not be removed.

Comment: thanks for all the edits!